# How can I give priority to one stylesheet over another on a Wordpress page template?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using a wordpress child theme and I have two page templates, the default template and another one I've called `full-page.php`.

My `style.css` is already overriding the stylesheet from the parent theme, and given that `full-page.php` template only has a few differences, I want its stylesheet - `full-page.css` to use the css from `style.css` (both from the parent and child theme), and make the necessary overrides to its specific template where needed.

My problem is that currently, any css code I write into `full-page.css` will work on the the correct template - `full-page.php`, but only if nothing has already been specified in `style.css`.

For example, if I want to change the color of my header to red on my `full-page.php` template, `background-color: red` will work when added to `full-page.css`, but if I have already specified `background-color: orange` on my default template, `style.css`, it will override the full page one.

Using `!important` works but I'd rather avoid this as it could cause further problems later down the line. Is there any way I can give priority to `full-page.css`and still allow it to keep using the default theme stylesheet and also the updates I've made in `style.css`?

```
<?php

 function my_et_enqueue_styles() {  

if (is_page_template('page-templates/full-page.php')) {

    wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'artwebsite-full-page', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/full-page.css', array( 'parent-style' ) );

}

else { 

     wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );

}

    
wp_enqueue_script( 'divi', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/scripts.js', array( 'jquery', 'divi-custom-script' ), '0.1.1', true );


}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_et_enqueue_styles' );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have the stylesheet with the element with the same specificity you want to load last. ( https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_specificity.asp )

So make sure that your specific ( full-page.css ) loads after your style.css

You can do this by changing making the full-page.css be *dependant* of the other so they cascade here is an example taken from the answer ( [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/91961/hook-wp-enqueue-scripts-priority-has-no-effect) )

```
function add_all_stylesheets() {
  wp_enqueue_style( 'stylesheet-one', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/stylesheet-one.css' );
  wp_enqueue_style( 'stylesheet-two', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/stylesheet-two.css', array( 'stylesheet-one' ) );
  wp_enqueue_style( 'stylesheet-three', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/stylesheet-three.css', array( 'stylesheet-two' ) );
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_all_stylesheets');
```

So in your child theme functions.php add:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_childtheme_add_stylesheets' );

function my_childtheme_add_stylesheets() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'my-child-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css', false, '1.0', 'all' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'artwebsite-full-page', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/full-page.css', array( 'my-child-style' ) );
}
```

Comment: Hi Ryan, thanks for your answer. Are you talking about the `array` command? I've used this in my code above, the only other difference I can see is the `if` and `else` commands that I need in order to differentiate between page templates.

Comment: style.css is a special style that is used for theming. Are you using a child theme? Can you provide more info on your parent theme and the load order of the scripts? As long as your full-page.css is loaded last it should take precedence. You could look for the last style sheet loaded and set that as the dependant.

Comment: I'm using the divi theme by Elegant Themes. I've just looked at the page source and it's loading the theme stylesheet first, then my full-page one (this is meant to be the dependent one) and finally it's loading style.css. I'm not sure why it's loading the main child theme stylesheet last, but I can't really make this the dependent one because this is where I've put the bulk of my styles and it needs to load on the default template. Is there a way I can keep the full-page stylesheet dependent on style.css and change the load order so it comes last?

Comment: Child themes are loaded before the parent, check here ( https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/#3-enqueue-stylesheet ) You may need to adjust how the parent theme loads styles if you want the child theme to take priority.

Comment: From what I can see in the page source in my browser, the parent theme stylesheet is loading first. It's the main child stylesheet that is cancelling out my full-page one. I can't figure out why.

Comment: You have array( 'parent-style' ) as a dependant. This is probably the parent theme stylesheet not the child theme. Make the child theme css the dependant, then the full-page.css will load after that. get_template_directory_uri() Will be for the parent theme and get_stylesheet_directory_uri() will be the child theme. Updated my answer

Comment: That worked, I've managed to get them loading in the right order, but for some strange reason the styles are still being overridden.. I think I'll check out the theme developer forum and see if I can find an answer. Thanks for your help Ryan :)

Comment: Turns out I had the wrong id selector for my child stylesheet, resulting in it being loaded twice and overwriting my second stylesheet.

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to have a style from a stylesheet coming earlier in the cascade overriding those that come later in the cascade is to use !important.

*Note: CSS = Cascading Style Sheet*

You could have full-page.css load after style.css if you want all the styles in full-page.css to override the styles in style.css.

If you want specific styles to override, then you need to use !important.

Comment: Hi Timothy, I'd rather avoid using !important. I've managed to make this work in a theme I built in an earlier project, but I've never tried it in a child theme. You mentioned I could have full-page.css load after style.css - do you know how I could edit my code to do this? I'm really new to PHP so any advice would be massively appreciated.